# Mass removal of link-only answers also removes internal links

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

Recenty the low quality queue became pretty big and it is full of answers containing a single link. I see that link-only answers are discouraged, because links can go dead and it is better to have the content on SO, but I wonder why answers containing in-site SO-links are also deleted.

For example, in this question the answer contains a duplicate question. The asker also marked the answer as helpful in a comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385075/smsreceived-event-on-android

*Now Deleted - Image for reference*

[image]

What is the correct thing to do here? Should I also flag the question as a duplicate/post a comment to the question to keep the link between the questions?

---

EDIT: Thanks the feedback, I've flagged the question as duplicate.

But the main problem in similar situations remain, as it is not the question but the answer that got into the review queue and I guess in most cases the answer is simply deleted (without the LQ-reviewer flagging the question as duplicate) - breaking the link between the questions.

Answer (score 8):

Answers having links pointing to other q/a on Stackoverflow is also discouraged. It may happen that the question is deleted, answer may be deleted which again makes the link only answer useless.

Also, if the question is duplicate, instead of answering the question, users should either flag it as a duplicate if he doesn't have closing rights, or he should be close voting the question as duplicate so that we get a single focused post with relevant answers, rather than having duplicate questions with one having answers pointing to the main question.

---

**As you edited your question**

*I guess in most cases the answer is simply deleted - breaking the link between the questions.*

It won't break the link, when you close vote a question as a duplicate, or comment as *possible duplicate*, Stackoverflow automatically links both the questions, take a look at the sidebar on that page.

[image: Linked Question]

---

**Second Edit in your question**

*I guess in most cases the answer is simply deleted (without the LQ-reviewer flagging the question as duplicate) - breaking the link between the questions.*

No, still it won't break.

Comment: Ok, but if in an other case the LQ-reviewer just deletes the link-only answer that also deletes the link.

Comment: @Csq No, that will not delete the link

Comment: "No, still it won't break." I'll try that out!

Comment: @Csq Sure. ....

Comment: @Csq: if someone has flagged it as a duplicate or there is a link to it in the question, an answer or a comment, it will not be removed. If no one posts the link elsewhere or flags it as a duplicate, then the link will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

You should vote to close the question.

Here an answer containing a link to another post on Stack Overflow helped and contained no other context, a clear indicator the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

There's a change in the works that will affect how easy it is to close a duplicate. Hint, much easier.

If:

- Someone posts a (mostly) link-only answer with a link to a separate answer on another question
- Both questions share tag similarities
- The question author *accepts* the answer pointing to another answer

... then the question is automatically marked as a duplicate. Nothing more needs to be done.

There's also an idea about letting you answer in a specific way that actually pulls in the content of another answer on another question (with all due attribution), gives you the opportunity to customize it more for the question at hand, and then post it. Same thing, if the author accepts it, automatically mark as a duplicate.

This has been in the works for a while, however tackling the quality problem is the first mountain we'd like to climb. While this *is* technically part of the perceived quality of the site, it's going to come after the q-blocks, filtering, just-in-time help / etc that we're doing now.

For now, yes - if it's obvious that the question author said (in some way) "yes this is what I wanted" then just vote to mark it as a duplicate. This is one of the reasons why we super-powered close votes for gold tag badge holders, there are just so many obvious cases.

Just remember, these duplicates *do* sometimes stick around as 'stubs' for the various ways people search, so don't discount their value - a little editorial love on something you know is going to be closed might be in order, use your best judgement.

Comment: What if I answer a question while citing other SO posts that happen to have similar tags, but those posts are not duplicates?

Comment: @Stijn There would be some conditions. You'd either have to leave a mostly-link answer (very common in these cases), or use the envisioned special way to vote to mark as a dup by answering, which would be very deliberate. Merely referencing wouldn't cause the behavior.

Comment: Would it make sense to add a close option to mark the question as a possible duplicate right in the queue?