# Can "barely more than a link to an external site" be reworded to include links to other answers?

Tags: feature-request, help-center

The [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) help page states that one reason answers are deleted is because they contain:

> barely more than a link to an external site

A few minutes ago a low-rep user posted an answer which was essentially nothing more than *"[link to a different Stack Overflow answer on another question] will tell you all you need to know"*. I commented on the answer saying that it would have been better suited as a comment instead. The user however then responded with *"please illuminate me why this is not an answer"*. My first port of call was to quote a relevant part of the Help section, but upon finding the most relevant page there isn't really anything there which caters for answers like this one.

The problem with the part I've quoted above is that it caters specifically to links to **external** websites and not links to other content within Stack Overflow (or the Stack Exchange network, if that counts as *internal*).

Could this be reworded to include links to other Stack Overflow content?

Comment: Couldn't the question be closed as a duplicate if it is asked/answered somewhere else on SO? Just a suggestion as I've not seen the posts in question. Isn't that the purpose of duplicates that differentiates it from links to external sites?

Comment: @Tanner yes that is what should have happened. The problem here is that the user is querying why their answer isn't an answer and the relevant Help documentation doesn't really tell them not to do it. A link to another answer is neither an "exact duplicate" nor "link to an external site", etc.

Comment: I guess in the absence of direct information in help you can always refer to meta posts too, perhaps this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/251594

Comment: @Tanner The comments on that answer are really interesting. Skeet arguing for link-only answers.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265683/mass-removal-of-link-only-answers-also-removes-internal-links

Comment: @Tanner agreed: if the question is already answered by another Q&A, then it's a duplicate. The appropriate thing is to mark it as a duplicate not to add answers which link to answers under another question.   If the question is entirely answered by some other free, volunteer-maintained site such as Wikipedia then it basically doesn't belong here; StackExchange shouldn't be redundant with respect to existing resources. There should be a close reason "This question is off topic because the subject matter is thoroughly treated by the following page: ".

Comment: @Kaz: it doesn't matter whether the question could be answered using some external resource: the answer may be wrong -- how do I post comment or downvote it on that external resource?

Comment: Ive seen questions where people go "the answer you want is in here" with a link to a different SO question. Keep in mind - that does NOT always mean its a duplicate. It just means the answer is somewhere in that question, maybe as a comment or an explanation elsewhere in that answer. But, I agree that perhaps the rule should be made to make this illegal because often I've clicked these links and been confused as to what the question had to do with my question.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You join that other excellent, free site and fix it there.

Comment: I think that answers should not just be deleted or even downvoted only because they consist of barely more than a link, if (and only if) the link points to a relevant answer. I dislike redundancy, so why repeat or rephrase an answer? Maybe the question really is a duplicate, but that is another topic. Sometimes I found answers by searching for a few key terms which did not directly lead me to the linked answer but to the seemingly useless duplicate(?) question which finally pointed me to the answer.

Comment: Unless or until the answer is really marked as a duplicate, someone providing a link to a correct answer does a good thing. A Q/A site like SO and even the WWW as a whole are hypertext systems which are alive because the concept of a link is one of their main features. Why should we punish users for using links if their usage makes sense?

Comment: @Kaz: _"This question is off topic because the subject matter is thoroughly treated by the following page"_ -- I'd love to have a very-limited-use close reason of "this is in the product documentation/specification/etc.". But one of the biggest reasons to not allow link-only answers is that they often refer to web pages that eventually change or disappear altogether. The only type of link that is a valid "answer" is one that is practically guaranteed never to change (e.g. an MSDN page for questions related to Microsoft technologies).

Comment: @Kaz: Frankly, I think even a strict version of that close reason would be misused. So while I would love to see it as an option, I also understand why it probably shouldn't be one.

Comment: @kriegaex: despite the 404 http error being a genius solution to a complex problem; it makes a link-only answer even less useful.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I do not understand your comment, honestly. What is the point you are trying to get across? To all: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/31703034/1082681, it just happened yesterday. This poor guy cannot close his own, answered question. Read the comments, please.

Comment: @kriegaex: a link-only answer with a broken link is not very useful -- is it clear?

Comment: I was talking about functioning links, not about broken ones. A link to another answer on SO or on something else like Spring documentation should not break easily. And if it does, bad luck. Let's try not to be such Nazi moderators. :-) (I may say that in this politically incorrect way, I am German.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the help could be clearer, and that even links to a Stack Overflow page are still not useful as an answer.

But as noted in some of the comments above, when the question has an actual answer on a different Stack Overflow page, then the correct way for a user to handle that is to vote to close the new question as a duplicate of the previous one. The help text should not only include Stack Overflow pages as a possible link target for these types of bad answers, but should clarify how users should handle such responses to questions, by explaining that need for an "as duplicate" close vote.

For that matter, I think that help page could stand to have elaboration for all of the several reasons listed. For example, for the "link to an external site" scenario, it would be helpful to guide users by explaining that answers that include such a link are not inherently bad, just that they need to include *more* than just that. Such as a quote or other summary of the linked-to content that does answer the question. That way, the answer can stand alone even if something happens to the external resource.

Looking at the whole list…

> •commentary on the question or other answers

Explain to users that commentary should be posted as a comment, not an answer. Also explain that we understand low-rep users can't comment, and that skirting that rule by posting a comment as an answer is simply not acceptable. Explain alternatives available to such low-rep users, such as moderation flags.

> •asking another, different question

Suggest to the user that different questions should be posted as new questions.

> •“thanks!” or “me too!” responses

Explain that such "chatty" responses are unnecessary, and generally considered "noise" rather than useful content.

> •exact duplicates of other answers

I'm not sure it should really be necessary to explain to users that plagiarism is not allowed, but I suppose a comprehensive help page would still restate that. :)

> •barely more than a link to an external site

See above.

> •not even a partial answer to the actual question

Like plagiarism, I'm not sure we should have to explain to users that answers should in fact be answers to the question that was asked. But again, being comprehensive could be helpful.

Note that when a *question* is closed for similar reasons, Stack Overflow does present the user with a short blurb explaining in a similar way to the above why their question was closed *and what they should do about it*. But I think that when an *answer* is closed, the feedback to the author of the answer is not necessarily as clear. A better help page could improve that situation.

Comment: I recommend adding a part for new, low rep users that says something like "if you find a duplicate question and do not have the Flag privilege, leave it for higher-rep users to flag".

Answer (score -8):

Fun fact: low rep users cannot post comments. Low rep users can also not flag posts as duplicates. The only choice for a low rep user who wants to answer a question that has already been answered is to reply with an answer that is "little more than a link". [Source 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5JDu.png). [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

In my opinion, changing the rule to apply it to that specific situation for the sole purpose of disallowing a new user to answer a question is silly. Let the new users answer questions and let the veterans and mods flag/vote as duplicate. This is supposedly a community, not an oligarchy.

Edit: I am not opposed to clarifying the help text. I posted this dissenting opinion for the sake of shaking up the then predominant "me too" comments. A small, prominently placed section that clearly says to avoid things that require more rep/privileges (e.g. leave duplicate questions alone if you don't have the Flag privilege) may be an equally useful addition.

Comment: *most* low rep users can flag as a duplicate.  That is the prefered solution to posting a link to another question as an answer

Comment: @psubsee2003 still, there are some who cannot. Should the more experienced users be hostile towards them for trying with the limited means afforded them?

Comment: it takes 10 rep to flag.  That handles most who actually want to try to answer.  If they have 10 rep, then I have no sympathy since they could flag.  If they have less than 10, I would flag for deletion (and vote for a duplicate), but I would at least not downvote them.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I suppose there are some ethical considerations here. And here's some random [cancer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31352524/2103394). It is somewhat [magical](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299029/2103394) how he managed to do it. I'm unconvinced that the proposed change is necessary for the education of new users when a user with 37.5k rep can post such an absurd answer.

Comment: He deleted his answer. I just can't stop laughing at that question.

Comment: "This is supposedly a community, not an oligarchy." hahahahahahahaha!!!

Comment: @JoeBlow happy to entertain :>

Comment: -1 Low rep users have also an alternative choice: **earn the damn few rep points to be able to comment**.

Comment: @Bakuriu How? The FGITW already took most of the clear questions by the time a new user sees them, and the unclear ones can't be answered without comments.

Comment: @tepples Edit suggestions are an extremely easy way to earn 50 re points in a few hours. And you **should** take a few hours to look around before posting anyways, to see how question are written, how are answered and how the votes etc are used.

Comment: @Bakuriu I was told earlier that edit suggestions waste reviewers' time, especially when they're retags. Let's [get a room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82747/room-for-tepples-and-nathanoliver).

Comment: @Bakuriu that is easier said than done for new users. Many of the questions worth answering are sniped by veterans before new users get a chance to write something, and many of the questions not sniped by veterans end up getting downvotes for the new user's answer, regardless of how accurate/helpful it is simply because the question was unpopular.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Correction: it takes 15 rep to cast most types of flag, but 50 to cast close-flags (which includes duplicates).

Comment: @1999 forgot about that limit.  Thank you for correcting me

Comment: @psubsee2003: A gentle reminder than the median reputation on SO is 1 rep. We can argue that those users have just registered and not attempted anything else, maybe, however it still means that more than 50% of SO users only have 1 rep, with all the privileges that entails.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: not only can you argue that most 1 rep users are not active, that's a fact. In any case, this being a community, no single person's knowledge is so critical to the community that they must be allowed to share that knowledge as a comment as their first action in the community. Either the info is more broadly known, and so someone else is likely to share the same info, or that person is highly skilled in their field, and will have no trouble at all gleaning the necessary rep in a short period of time. Go past the first page of questions...there are plenty left to answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes, but in the case of reporting duplicates, new users who _are trying to be active_ can neither post comments nor vote to close as a duplicate. They are essentially penalized by higher rep users for _trying to be helpful in the only way they can_. The help text can be changed to clarify the proper course of action for duplicate questions, but that will do nothing for new users unless it states something to the effect of "leave duplicates alone for higher rep users to close".

Comment: [How should low-rep users approach issues that could be solved by permissions they don't have access to?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290323)

Comment: @Deduplicator nice. But shouldn't that kind of discussion be somewhere in the help texts?

Comment: @NathanOliver that was something tepples said, not I.

Comment: @JonathanVoss Sorry about that.

Comment: @tepples Edit suggestions don't waste reviewers time. That's what they are there for. I said something to you on edits that only retag as part of a retagtging initiative as there are other people who can handle that, If you can go into a post and edit it to make it better then go ahead and do it.

Comment: The help-center does not provide exhaustive rationale for all the design choices. Whether one can make the case for adding such a disclaimer... I'm dubious it would help any.

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree, fwiw :>

Comment: @Deduplicator This whole discussion is about adding to the help text to clarify the workings and expectations of the community for new users.

Comment: "*trying to be helpful in the only way they can*." -- if someone tries to be helpful, but is not helpful, do you praise them or tell them to stop?  Remember, the biggest audience for SO isn't the Original Poster, but rather someone else who has the same problem.  And SO has decided the best way to serve those Other Users with the same problem is to enforce certain rules about what an answer is.  Imagine some civilian stepping into the intersection directing traffic because a yellow light bulb burnt out on a traffic light: "trying to be helpful", but really isn't.

Comment: @Yakk Point taken