# How can an answer less than 30 characters be posted?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, character-limit

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31352524/1586200) answer which has only 4 characters - "Yes.". Till now, I used to think that the answer should have >= 30 characters.

I tried answering on that question which has <30 character, something like - "Works.", but the system won't let me do it.

Does it have to do with the user's reputation by any chance?

Comment: Dunno. `<!--well maybe i actually do-->`

Comment: Ya, even I figured it. `<br>                                                 <br>` ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nothing to do with the user's reputation; the likelihood is that they added non-printable characters to pad out the 30 character requirement.

In this scenario, though, this is a non-answer.  The question is also poor, as Matlab would tell you whether it's valid syntax or not straight away.

Answer (score 22):

View the post revision's [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12b365b0-adf8-469c-b22e-443fed5b11ee/view-source), which shows what seems to be two extra spaces after the period.  It's actually a bunch of non-printable characters:

```
Yes.\u200f\u200f\u200f \u200f\u200f \u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f\u200f
```

Comment: So, we just need a check for nonprintables.

Comment: @AJFarmar : or, rather, a check that **doesn't** take into account non-printables. Looks like the current one is too smart for its own good.

Comment: @mikołak Har, har; I meant as in cheking if a character is nonprintable, and not including it in the overall character count if it is.

Comment: If someone goes to that much trouble to avoid a minimum length I would be inclined to accept it--they obviously have a good reason to think it's a proper answer, they aren't just being lazy.  While I have never hit it here there's another board I'm active on with a rule that a message must contain at least two non-quoted characters.  More than once it's saved me from a focus error causing an attempt to post only a quote--but I've also deliberately posted a message consisting only of quote**s** and some hidden text to make it postable.